# Check if jQuery "Fancybox" is already registered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fancybox

I'm regestering a jQuery fancybox like so:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#help").fancybox({
            'width': '90%',
            'height': '90%',
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'titleShow': false,
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
         });
```

However, on page transfer/postback it is getting registered multiple times, which slows it down to the point of breaking. Is there a way to check if the event is already registered, and if not, register it?

Pseudo code:

```
 //check if fancybox has not been registered
if($("help").fancybox == null))
{
     //register fancy box
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When fancybox runs, it adds a `fancybox` entry into jQuery's `data` object.

You can test for its presence:

```
if( ! $("#help").data().fancybox )
{
     //register fancy box
}
```

Comment: Fancybox 2 doesn't seem to do this. At least not in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Fancybox uses $(element).data() to store its element related configuration. You just have to check if a `fancybox` exists.

```
$("#fancy").data("fancybox");
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaBaballe/Dra7g/) for more fnu.

Answer (score 1):

This Function looks for your `#help` Element and loads the fancybox.js only if it's present. After successfully loading the Fancybox.js it'll call the success function and init your fancybox.

This will only affect pages which have the element `#help`. So you save HTTP Requests and bandwidth.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You should also look for the `error function` which allows you to handle errors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Look for #help
    if ( $('#help').html() !== null ) {

        // Load, init and config the fancybox
        $.ajax({
            url: '/js/path/to/fancybox.js',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function() {

                // Init Fancybox
                $("#help").fancybox({
                    'width': '90%',
                    'height': '90%',
                    'autoScale': true,
                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'titleShow': false,
                    'type': 'iframe'
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but for Fancybox 2 I use:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.isOpen
```

I think that you can also use:

parent.jQuery.fancybox.isOpened

Both statements will return true if fancybox is open on the site.