# Check if jQuery Plugin has been applied to Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, how can I check whether a specific plugin is active on an element? Alternatively, can I get a list of which elements a specific plugin has been applied to?

I have no control of the plugin's code. I've tried checking a property like

```
$("#example").fancybox
```

but this property exists for every element, regardless of whether the plugin has been applied.

Thanks!

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247363/check-if-jquery-fancybox-is-already-registered

Comment: Fancybox was just an example, I'm looking for a way that will work on most/all jquery plugins

Comment: Have you tried checking jQuery's `data()` function? I think it is entirely down to the plugin developer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no obligation for a plugin to advertise to the outside world the fact that it has augmented an element.

That said, many plugins (including anything that uses the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/)) register their names with the element using jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) facility. Then again, not all plugins do that.